# List attachments from the contact in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, email-filter

In Outlook 2016, how do you list all attachments from the contact?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

Open the contact. You'll see attachments in its Notes section.

Comment: Could you show me a picture, when I open contact--->Notes --> "No notes have been added"